# Couldn't get Design Time license for 'SoftwareFX.ChartFX.Chart' error in C# solution

Tags: c#, visual-studio, chartfx

I'm trying to build a C# solution in Visual Studio 2008 written by other programmer. Visual Studio throws the following error:

> Exception occurred creating type
>   'SoftwareFX.ChartFX.Chart, ChartFX,
>   Version=6.2.1342.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=a1878e2052c08dce'
>   System.ComponentModel.LicenseException:
>   Couldn't get Design Time license for
>   'SoftwareFX.ChartFX.Chart'

I've never used SoftwareFX or ChartFX. Actually I'm C/C++ developer, not C# developer but have to debug this project. How to resolve this issue?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Well, that will make it compile but it will fail at run-time when you try to display a chart in your app in a computer that doesn't have a Chart FX license.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to install a licensed version of [ChartFX](http://www.softwarefx.com/sfxNetProducts/ChartFX/), then reopen Visual Studio, and this should go away.

The error message is saying that you're trying to build a project that uses ChartFX, but do not have a valid license.

Answer (score 5):

I've found a way: making `licenses.licx` file a 0 byte file. After this the solution builds.

Answer (score 1):

Here is what you need to do. Simply open the form which contains the chart and just click on the chart once. This will create the license.licx file you need. Alternatively just create a new form and add the chart to this form. Compile the solution and delete the new form and you should be all sorted!

Answer (score 1):

My problem was that ChartFX trial license had expired and I had bought a new license to use.
Clearing licenses.licx helped me solved my problem.